# Use JAXB with plexus-compiler-eclipse plugin in maven profile

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jaxb

I am working on a project where we want to use the `plexus-compiler-eclipse` plugin during a Jenkins pipeline to check for increases in the number of warnings generated by the Eclipse compiler. We still want to use the `javac` compiler for the normal build and test stage, so I am trying to create a maven profile we can run during the warnings stage that utilizes the Eclipse compiler.

When I run the Eclipse compiler over our code, I get a compile error about JAXB dependencies being missing. I know this is due to our move to Java 11 from Java 1.8, but we do not get this error when building with the `javac` compiler. I have tried adding the `jakarta.xml.bind-api` dependency to the `maven-compiler-plugin`, but this does not help, nor does adding the `org.glassfish.jaxb` dependency or the `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api` dependency.

I cannot share the full pom because this project is proprietary, but the profile I'm building looks like this:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>eclipse-compile</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1></version>
                    <configuration>
                        <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <compilerArguments>
                            <properties>${project.basedir}/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs</properties>
                        </compilerArguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                            <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
                            <version>2.8.8</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
                            <version>3.25.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</profile>
```

I was putting the various JAXB dependencies I tried in the `<dependencies>` section under the `org.eclipse.jdt` entry.

Anyone else encounter this or know what to do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stemmed from the Maven build running in Java 11 but our normal compile stage forking to a Java 1.8 executable. Because the Plexus compiler cannot fork to a new environment, there was not a way for it to access the Java EE dependencies. We just need to update our entire project to be compatible with Java 11 at compile-time.